# Prove or disprove: $ A^2 = I \Longrightarrow A=I \vee A=-I $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Linear Algebra/ Matrices

A is in a $n\times n$ matrix.
If
$$ A^2 = I $$
does this imply: $A=I \vee A=-I $

Thanks!

Comment: When you write $\longrightarrow$ I suspect you ought to write $\implies$. Although $\longrightarrow$ is common in logic, the symbol $\implies$ is used far more frequently in mathematics. We write $A \implies B$ to mean $A$ *implies* $B$, or *if* $A$ *then* $B$, or $A$ *is a sufficient condition for* $B$.

Comment: Corrected. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Here are two counterexamples (with their interpretation in $\Bbb R^2)$:

Symmetry with respect to the $x$ axis:  $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that any symmetry would work. For example: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

---

By the way, this would be true in a field because

$X^2=I\iff X^2-I=0\iff X^2-I^2=0\iff (X-I)(X+I)=0$

but the matrices only form a ring, not a field so we don't have $(X-I)(X+I)=0 \implies X-I=0\lor X+I=0$

Comment: Great, thanks.  
But, How did you come up with those counterexamples?
I mean, what was the way of thinking?

Comment: @captain dragon : These matrix represent symmetries (with respect to a line but taking a symmetry with respect to a point would work too) and those transformations are clearly involutive (their square is the identity).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to come up with a counterexample if you think in terms of linear maps. A map $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $T(x, y) = (y, x)$ clearly satisfies $T^2 = I$ and $T \not\in \{I, -I\}$. The matrix of this map is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: More generally any matrix $E$ obtained by switching two rows of the identity has the property that $E^2=E$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c& d}.
$$
Then compute 
$$
A^2 = \pmatrix{a^2 + bc & ab + bd \\ ac + cd & bc + d^2}
$$ and see if you can find $a,b,c,d$ such that $A^2 = I$ but $A \neq I, -I$. (You should be able to do this).

Comment: @captaindragon: Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, we then have the eigenvalues of $A$ to be either $+1$ or $-1$. Hence, $$A = \begin{bmatrix} \pm 1& 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & \pm1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \pm 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S = \{ s_1 ... s_d \}$ is a set of distinct complex numbers.
Then the equation

$$(A-s_1 I)(A-s_2 I)...(A-s_d I) = 0 $$

implies that $A$ must be expressible as:

$$A = B D B^{-1}$$

where $B$ is some invertible matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries from the set $S$. That is, $A$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues must be a subset of $S$.

In this case $S = \{-1,+1\}$. So the equation $A^2-I = (A-I)(A+I) = 0$
implies that $A = B D B^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal with entries $\{-1,+1\}$ on the diagonal. Note that if all the diagonal entries of $D$ are the same then this implies $A=I$ or $A=-I$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $\psi: V \rightarrow V$ such that $\psi(v)=v-Av$. Now prove that V=Ker$(\psi)$ $\oplus$ Im$(\psi)$. Now observe that Ker$(\psi)=V_{1}$ and Im$(\psi)=V_{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$A=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\pm I & \text{,if } \det(A) = 1 \\
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & -a \end{bmatrix} & \text{,if } \det(A) = -1
\end{array}
\right.$

Proof:

[image: proof]